# Bash not interpreting line as usable string for UFW

Tags: bash, ufw

I am trying to block Digital Ocean IP addresses automatically based on an API request.  It creates a text file that simply looks like:

```
103.253.144.0/22
104.131.0.0/18
104.131.128.0/20
104.131.144.0/20
```

If I manually type the command:

```
$ sudo ufw insert 1 deny from 103.253.144.0/22 to any
```

The result is

```
Rule inserted
```

In my simple bash script when running the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "Inserting: $line"
    ufw insert 1 deny from "$line" to any
    sleep 2
    exit 1
done < ocean.txt
```

I get

```
Inserting: 103.253.144.0/22
ERROR: Bad source address
```

I am assuming that bash is interpreting $line incorrectly ..  I even thought it might be an array element, so I tried `"{{ line }}"` as well to no avail.  What am I doing wrong here? this seems so basic!

Here is the output of `bash -x`

```
+ IFS=
+ read -r line
' echo 'Inserting: 103.253.144.0/22
Inserting: 103.253.144.0/22
+ ufw insert 1 deny from $'103.253.144.0/22\r' to any
ERROR: Bad source address
+ sleep 2
+ exit 1
```

Comment: What good is a `while` loop with an `exit` inside it? You're ignoring everything but the first line; might as well not loop at all.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy the `exit` is so that it only runs 1 iteration for my test .. Which is failing ..  I will remove the `exit` once I can actually get the rule to insert.

Comment: If you do want to only read the first line, you don't need any loop at all; `IFS= read -r line <ocean.txt` works perfectly well on its own.

Comment: That said, if you want to loop _until `ufw` fails_, then put `|| exit` after the `ufw` line and ufw failing will cause the script to immediately abort.

Comment: And use `bash -x yourscript` to log what it's doing; that log will show if there's something like nonprintable characters in your input file. You can also put the line `set -x` inside the script.

Comment: If `bash -x` or `set -x` shows you `$'103.253.144.0/23\r'`, that tells you your input file is saved in DOS format instead of as a UNIX text file.

Comment: ...if that were the case, the question would be duplicative of [Are shell scripts sensitive to encodings and line endings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39527571/are-shell-scripts-sensitive-to-encoding-and-line-endings)

Comment: Updated with output of `-x`

Comment: Which would be what you are talking about  .. The `\r` line ending?

Comment: Yup. `dos2unix ocean.txt` is your quick solution. You can also change `IFS=` to `IFS=$'\r'` before the `read`, or use any of the other solutions described in the linked duplicate.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you .. No need to close the question .. I will delete it .. Unless you think it would be a valuable question to close and forward to the duplicate ..  Either way, delete or mark duplicate.  Thank you.

Comment: I think it's fine to leave it as a duplicate -- if it gets search hits or upvotes the system will keep it, if it doesn't it'll eventually get reaped.